# Binding data From Three different tables in a single query and again displaying as three different sections in crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have three different tables:

- Employ payment
- Miscellaneous payment
- Other category of payment

All have a common field. `project id`.

Now I want the details to be displayed on a crystal report.When i select based on particular project.

And for which some how i wrote a stored procedure which binds all the three tables and provides all the parameters required in a single query..

But i am failing in getting the required information in three different sections. with column name and data  separately Like:

```
table1Column table1Column 
table1Data   table1Data


table2Column table2Column 
table2data table2data

table3column table2column
table3data table3data
```

Could you please help me on it.I was stuck with this. Please help me with having the records get displayed on crystal reports in three different sectiosn

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all three tables have the same count of columns.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM employ_payment) a
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM misc_payment) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM other_category_payment)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Give this a try:

```
SELECT table1.Column, table2.Column, table3.column
FROM table1
JOIN table2.Column ON project id
JOIN table3.Column ON project id
```

Answer (score 0):

don't create a stored procedure instead follow below process.

```
1. Take a report and insert 3 sub reports in that report, If you wish take 3 tables in main report and link those in links option using the `project ID`.
2. In sub report 1 take table1 and link to main report and place columns as per your requirement.
2. In sub report 2 take table 2 and link to main report and place columns as per your requirement.
3. In sub report 3 take table 3 and link to main report and place columns as per your requirement.
4. Now run the report you have the desired output.
```

Comment: But For having 3tables in main Report.I am not get how to do,And also i am using a stored procedure,where i pass the parameter from the code, when i am loading the crystal report.And i tried doing the way of creating a sub reports for each section.But there its asking for the parameter value mentioned above.Could you please help me on it

Comment: for parameter it is not compulsory to have stored procedure you can locally create in crystal report. Create parameter in main report and also in all the 3 subreports now link the parameter value with main report. This way you can solve the problem